# Ionic4 custom camera view

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to create a custom frame for the camera in Ionic4, like snapchat filters, id like to add frames around the edge of the camera while it is active. Is this possible in ionic?

Im currently just importing the usual camera functionality

```
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
```

then

```
 takeSnap() {
    this.camera.getPicture(this.cameraOptions).then((imageData) => {
      // this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI gives file URI saved in local
      // this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL gives base64 URI

      let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.capturedSnapURL = base64Image;
    }, (err) => {

      console.log(err);
      // Handle error
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.

To have this level of control means you would need to write some native code.

Ionic is just using the plugin to call native device functionality.

If you dig into the code you will find that the Ionic Native plugin uses Cordova Plugin Camera.

You would need to create your own fork of this project and then write code in Java and Objective-C for the android and IOS versions.

You can see the code they have written so far here:

- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/tree/master/src

You would be on your own for a project like this - I've never seen any tutorials about these topics.

You would need to learn to code in those languages, then how to do the graphics coding to take control of the camera, and then after that the theory of building image filters and AR filters.

The smarter option would be to allow the frames to be added to the image after it has been taken. This would still be a research task, but it would cut out a ton of your requirements and you could do it all in TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i did see a native plugin "cordova-camera-preivew" which allows overlay over the camera. Although its not working for me in ionic4 im building a new version in ionic3 i will try to use it there.

Comment: Ah I thought the camera preview was just for when you wanted to display a "live" thumbnail at the start of a grid. I didn't realise it had full screen options.

Answer (score 0):

In ionic you can't do that but after photo captured you can add filters like snap-chat you can use this library for that

```
http://fabricjs.com/
```